# Bootstrap no me reconoce col

Tags: bootstrap

estoy reformando una página con bootstrap y al cambiar a la versión movil no me reconoce los col. La versión de bootstrap es un poco antigua pero si está todo bien puesto debería de funcionar, he probado a cambiar de versión de bootstrap pero me retoca todos los estilos. Estoy abierto a recomendaciones.
Lo que quiero hacer es en unas cajas, que son tres se me muestre las 3 en línea en pc, dos arriba y una abajo tablet, y de una en una en móvil.
Mi código:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

```
        <!--<div class="frontal container-fluid my-4 text-center text-uppercase"> 
            <h2>Nos esforzamos porque el cliente tenga todas las necesidades cubiertas.</h2>
        </div>-->

        <div class="container">
            <div class="row my-5 text-center">

                <!--Item-->                    
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="card-img-topfal fal fa-laptop-medical fa-3x mt-4"></i>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente texto de relleno de la industria de la impresión y la composición tipográfica. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el.</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Fin item-->

                <!--Item-->
                <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="card-img-top fal fa-user-tag fa-3x mt-4"></i>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente texto de relleno de la industria de la impresión y la composición tipográfica. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Fin item-->

                <!--Item-->

                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="card">
                        <a href="#">
                            <i class="card-img-top fal fa-user-tag fa-3x mt-4"></i>
                            <div class="card-body">
                                <h3 class="card-title text-uppercase">Lorem Ipsum</h3>
                                <p class="card-text">Lorem Ipsum es simplemente texto de relleno de la industria de la impresión y la composición tipográfica. Lorem Ipsum ha sido el</p>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <!--Fin item-->
                
            </div><!--row-->
        </div><!--container-->
           
    </section>
    <!--Fin seccion cajas-->


    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Según las medidas se debe ocupar distintos prefijos como:
Extra small < 576px -> `.col-`
Small ≥ 576px -> `.col-sm-`
Medium ≥ 768px -> `.col-md-`
Large ≥ 992px -> `.col-lg-`
Extra large ≥ 1200px -> `.col-xl-`

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">COL 1</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-6 col-lg-4">COL 2</div>
  <div class="col-12 col-lg-4">COL 3</div>
</div>
```

Entonces cuando esta en "modo pc" se está utilizando `col-lg-4` en cada col, y cuando está en "modo tablet" se está utilizando `col-md-6` en las dos primeras col, y para celulares se utiliza `col-12` en las 3 col.

Comment: Gracias compañero, lo he probado pero no me reconoce el cambio, me sigue mostrando en la versión móvil las tres juntas. No hace los col.

Comment: @77hector77 que raro, en el ejemplo que puse se está usando el mismo link que utilizas, prueba borrando el caché de tu navegador, o prueba en otro navegador

Comment: Si compañero, ha funcionado, le he borrado la cache al chrome y funciona, llevaba días con ese error. Ahora lo probé en opera y firefox y se me quedaba igual sin reconocer los col, y ni borrando cache, cuando me llegan estos errores ya me pierdo. Muchísimas gracias

Comment: Ojo, [¡col-xs ya no funciona en la versión 4 de Bootstrap!](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/#grid-system)

Comment: @padaleiana Verdad!, ya edité la respuesta.